# Sustituir una familia de palabras

Tags: r, regex

Tengo el siguiente df

```
datos2<-data.frame(
  col1=c("verde pre verde verde","Amarillo premiu morado rojo ","Azul pr verde4","234 prem amarillo verde","rojo prem verde verde","azul premi rojo negro"),
  col2=c(123,234,222,111,456,345)
)
```

```
              col1             col2
1        verde pre verde verde  123
2 Amarillo premiu morado rojo   234
3               Azul pr verde4  222
4      234 prem amarillo verde  111
5        rojo prem verde verde  456
6        azul premi rojo negro  345
```

Quiero sustituir las palabras pr, pre, prem, premi, premiu por Premium

Hago lo siguiente:

```
datos2$col1 <- gsub(" pr.* " , " Premium ", datos2$col1)
```

```
         col1          col2
1 verde Premium verde  123
2   Amarillo Premium   234
3 Azul Premium verde4  222
4   234 Premium verde  111
5  rojo Premium verde  456
6  azul Premium negro  345
```

¿Por qué desaparecen algunos de los colores que van detrás de la palabra Premium?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al colocar la expresiòn regular `" pr.* "` le estas indicando que busque los caracteres que tienen antes de la `p` un espacio y que al final esté un espacio. Cuando encuentre toda esa especificación lo reemplazará por `premium`. Por eso en tu segunda fila al ser `"Amarillo premiu morado rojo "`, si te fijas termina en espacio. Por eso encuentra la coincidencia hasta el último caracter.

Las expresiones regulares buscan la coincidencia más larga, es decir, hasta el máximo donde se cumple. No sólo la primera coincidencia.

Ahora una posible solución sería la siguiente:

```
datos2$mio<-gsub("pr|pre|prem|premi|premiu", "Premium", datos2$col1)
```

a lo que te quedaría de la siguiente manera tu data frame.

```
datos2
                      original col2             lo_tuyo                           mio
1        verde pre verde verde  123 verde Premium verde     verde Premium verde verde
2 Amarillo premiu morado rojo   234   Amarillo Premium  Amarillo Premium morado rojo 
3               Azul pr verde4  222 Azul Premium verde4           Azul Premium verde4
4      234 prem amarillo verde  111   234 Premium verde    234 Premium amarillo verde
5        rojo prem verde verde  456  rojo Premium verde      rojo Premium verde verde
6        azul premi rojo negro  345  azul Premium negro       azul Premium rojo negro
```

En expresiones regulares el símbolo `|` actúa como una `o` condicional.

Otra posible solución sería si usas la expresión regular `?`. De la siguiente manera.

```
datos2$mio_2<-gsub(" pr.*? ", " Premium ", datos2$col1)
```

A lo que te arrojará el mismo resultado. La expresión `?` le indica a R que busque la primera coincidencia. Y no la máxima como estaba definido tu expresión regular.

Answer (score 1):

Desaparece porque le estas diciendo a R que reemplace todo lo que está entr `pr` y un espacio y en consecuencia toma todo hasta el último espacio que encuentra. Prueba:

```
datos2$col1 <- gsub("pr[A-Z,a-z]* " , " Premium ", datos2$col1)
```

Sustituirá las palabras que inicien con `pr`, pero ojo que eso incluirá palabras como `privado`, `premio`, etc. Por lo que te recomiendo el siguiente código:

```
datos2$col1 <- gsub("\\<(pr|pre|prem|premi|premiu)\\>" , " Premium ", datos2$col1)
```

De esta manera sustituirás estrictamente las palabras que quieres.

Answer (score 1):

El problema básico, no está necesariamente en tu patrón, sino, es que la forma básica en la que operan las expresiones regulares en R, es la forma "hambrienta" ("greedy"), esto es, se trata de coincidir con la mayor cantidad de caracteres posibles, por eso cuando haces:

```
gsub(" pr.* " , " Premiun ", "verde pre verde verde")
[1] "verde Premiun verde"
```

Estas buscando `espacio` + `pr` + `cualquier caracter` y el cualquier carácter, incluye al espacio, por lo que se hace coincidir la cadena hasta el último espacio disponible, básicamente `[verde pre verde ]verde"`. Hay formas varias para solventar esto. Lo más simple, o al menos lo que permite respetar tu patrón original, es modificar la modalidad de las expresiones regulares por una "no hambrienta", por lo que el espacio final del patrón, se hará coincidir con el primero y no con el último disponible:

```
datos2$col3 <- gsub("(?U) pr.* " , " Premiun ", datos2$col1)
datos2

                          col1 col2                          col3
1        verde pre verde verde  123     verde Premiun verde verde
2 Amarillo premiu morado rojo   234 Amarillo Premiun morado rojo 
3               Azul pr verde4  222           Azul Premiun verde4
4      234 prem amarillo verde  111    234 Premiun amarillo verde
5        rojo prem verde verde  456      rojo Premiun verde verde
6        azul premi rojo negro  345       azul Premiun rojo negro
```

Usamos `(?U)` para configurar el modo "not greedy", para más referencias, es muy útil [esta hoja de trucos](https://rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/RegExCheatsheet.pdf).